# Securing config file containing plain-text passwords only with file-system permissions?

Tags: ubuntu, security

I have read a lot of posts and questions about the safest way to secure your server configuration files, which contain sensitive information, such as passwords. The 3 main recommendations I have found so far are :

- don't put your sensitive info in source control (OK)
- set passwords and other credentials as environment variables (?)
- make sure the files containing these variables have the right permissions so that no one can read them (?)

My deployment is so that I have created one normal user for the server (with no special privileges), and the configuration file is in its home directory. Is it enough if I set permissions to this file to 600? `chmod 600 ~/config` ? Why would I need environment variables since they are anyways stored in plain text in a file as well? is there any way I can be more secure than this?